# Parameter pack expansion for static variables

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I am thinking about following problem:

Let us have a merging function for merge arrays defined in following way:

```
// input is (const void*, size_t,  const void*, size_t,...)
template<typename...ARGS>
MyArray Concatenation(ARGS...args)
```

And let us have couple of structs with static properties

```
struct A { static void* DATA; static size_t SIZE; };
struct B { static void* DATA; static size_t SIZE; };
struct C { static void* DATA; static size_t SIZE; };
```

I would like to have a method:

```
template<typename...ARGS>
MyArray AutoConcatenation();
```

Where ARGS should be structs with mentioned static interface.
Following methods should have the same output:

```
AutoConcatenation<A, B, C>();
Concatenation(A::DATA, A::SIZE, B::DATA, B::SIZE, C::DATA, C::SIZE);
```

My question is how to implement parameter pack expansion.

I tried:

```
// not working
template<typename...ARGS>
MyArray AutoConcatenation()
{
  return Concatenation((ARGS::DATA, ARGS::SIZE)...);
}
```

What about expansions

```
ARGS::DATA... // Correct expansion of pointers
ARGS::SIZE... // Correct expansion of sizes
(ARGS::DATA, ARGS::SIZE)... // Seems to be expansion of sizes
```

Just info for advisors. I am looking for implementation of **AutoConcatenation** method, not for its redeclaration nor for redeclaration previous code, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by *Concatenation*?

Comment: It does not matter. Solution is independent on semantic of functions. For your information, if DATA would be c strings, A::DATA = "abc", A::SIZE = 3, Concatenation(A::DATA, A::SIZE, A::DATA, A::SIZE) would be array with data "abcabc" and size 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lazy solution using `std::tuple`:

- make a tuple of `DATA` and `SIZE` for each element of the parameter pack,
- flatten the list of tuples to one big tuple using `std::tuple_cat`,
- apply the resulting tuple's elements to `Concatenation` by expanding a list of indexes in an `std::index_sequence`.

In the following code, the test harness is longer than the actual solution:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>

struct MyArray { };
template<class... ARGS> MyArray Concatenation(ARGS... args) 
{
   // Just some dummy code for testing.
   using arr = int[];
   (void)arr{(std::cout << typeid(args).name() << ' ' << args << '\n' , 0)...};
   return {}; 
}

struct A { static void* DATA; static std::size_t SIZE; };
struct B { static void* DATA; static std::size_t SIZE; };
struct C { static void* DATA; static std::size_t SIZE; };

// Also needed for testing.
void* A::DATA;
std::size_t A::SIZE;
void* B::DATA;
std::size_t B::SIZE;
void* C::DATA;
std::size_t C::SIZE;


// The useful stuff starts here.

template<class T, std::size_t... Is> MyArray concat_hlp_2(const T& tup, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
   return Concatenation(std::get<Is>(tup)...);
}

template<class T> MyArray concat_hlp_1(const T& tup)
{
   return concat_hlp_2(tup, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<T>::value>{});
}

template<class... ARGS> MyArray AutoConcatenation()
{
   return concat_hlp_1(std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(ARGS::DATA, ARGS::SIZE)...));
}


int main()
{
   AutoConcatenation<A, B, C>();
}
```

---

If you want to avoid `std::tuple` and `std::tuple_cat` (which can be heavy in terms of compile times), here's an alternative using indexes into arrays.

The testing code stays the same, this is just the juicy stuff:

```
template<std::size_t Size> const void* select(std::false_type, std::size_t idx,
   const void* (& arr_data)[Size], std::size_t (&)[Size])
{
   return arr_data[idx];
}

template<std::size_t Size> std::size_t select(std::true_type, std::size_t idx,
   const void* (&)[Size], std::size_t (& arr_size)[Size])
{
   return arr_size[idx];
}

template<std::size_t... Is> MyArray concat_hlp(std::index_sequence<Is...>, 
   const void* (&& arr_data)[sizeof...(Is) / 2], std::size_t (&& arr_size)[sizeof...(Is) / 2])
{
   return Concatenation(select(std::bool_constant<Is % 2>{}, Is / 2, arr_data, arr_size)...);
}

template<class... ARGS> MyArray AutoConcatenation()
{
   return concat_hlp(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(ARGS) * 2>{}, {ARGS::DATA...}, {ARGS::SIZE...});
}
```

Again a sequence of indexes twice the size of the original parameter pack, but we build separate arrays of `DATA` and `SIZE` and then use tag dispatching to select elements from one or the other depending on the parity of the current index.

This may not look as nice as the previous code, but it doesn't involve any template recursion (`std::make_index_sequence` is implemented using compiler intrinsics in modern compilers as far as I know) and cuts down on the number of template instantiations, so it should be faster to compile.

The `select` helper can be made `constexpr` by using arrays of pointers to the static members, but this turns out to be unnecessary in practice. I've tested MSVC 2015 U2, Clang 3.8.0 and GCC 6.1.0 and they all optimize this to a direct call to `Concatenation` (just like for the tuple-based solution).

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible solution:

```
enum Delimiters { Delimiter };
const void* findData(size_t count) { return nullptr; }

template<typename...ARGS>
const void* findData(size_t count, size_t, ARGS...args)
{
    return findData(count, args...); 
}

template<typename...ARGS>
const void* findData(size_t count, const void* data, ARGS...args) 
{ 
    return count ? findData(count - 1, args...) : data; 
}

template<typename...ARGS>
MyArray reordered(size_t count, Delimiters, ARGS...args) 
{
    return Concatenate(args...); 
}

template<typename...ARGS>
MyArray reordered(size_t count, const void* size, ARGS...args) 
{ 
    return reordered(count, args...); 
}

template<typename...ARGS>
MyArray reordered(size_t count, size_t size, ARGS...args) 
{ 
    return reordered(count + 1, args..., findData(count, args...), size); 
}

template<typename...ARGS>
MyArray AutoConcatenate()
{
    return reordered(0, ARGS::LAYOUT_SIZE..., ARGS::LAYOUT..., Delimiter);
}
```

**If you know more elegant way, please let me know.**

**EDIT**

One little more elegant way is to keep function argument *count* as template parameter...

Comment: In general, answering your own question is not customary. Perhaps you should just add this to your original post, and change your post to ask for a more elegant solution.

Comment: @William There is nothing wrong about asking your own question.

Comment: @Zerges, sure. What about answering it? Especially not giving it even a day? Besides, I don't recall calling it "wrong."

Comment: Note that you'd need to make a couple of small changes to this code to make it standard-compliant (I suppose you've tested it using Visual C++, which still doesn't implement two-phase lookup): you need to forward-declare `template<typename...ARGS> const void* findData(size_t count, const void* data, ARGS...args);` and `template<typename...ARGS> MyArray reordered(size_t count, size_t size, ARGS...args);`. To see the nice error messages, you can try compiling on Clang or a reasonably recent version of GCC.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is more elegant, and it illustrates the common recursive unpacking pattern. Finally, it does not perform any voodoo with memory layouts and tries to be idiomatic as far as C++ generic programming.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Handle zero arguments.
template <typename T = string>
T concat_helper() { return T(); }

// Handle one pair.
template <typename T = string>
T concat_helper(const T &first, size_t flen) { return first; }

// Handle two or more pairs. Demonstrates the recursive unpacking pattern
// (very common with variadic arguments).
template <typename T = string, typename ...ARGS>
T concat_helper(const T &first, size_t flen,
                const T &second, size_t slen,
                ARGS ... rest) {
  // Your concatenation code goes here. We're assuming we're
  // working with std::string, or anything that has method length() and
  // substr(), with obvious behavior, and supports the + operator.
  T concatenated = first.substr(0, flen) + second.substr(0, slen);
  return concat_helper<T>(concatenated, concatenated.length(), rest...);
}

template <typename T, typename ...ARGS>
T Concatenate(ARGS...args) { return concat_helper<T>(args...); }

template <typename T>
struct pack {
  T data;
  size_t dlen;
};

template <typename T>
T AutoConcatenate_helper() { return T(); }

template <typename T>
T AutoConcatenate_helper(const pack<T> *packet) {
  return packet->data;
}

template <typename T, typename ...ARGS>
T AutoConcatenate_helper(const pack<T> *first, const pack<T> *second,
                         ARGS...rest) {
  T concatenated = Concatenate<T>(first->data, first->dlen,
                                  second->data, second->dlen);
  pack<T> newPack;
  newPack.data = concatenated;
  newPack.dlen = concatenated.length();

  return AutoConcatenate_helper<T>(&newPack, rest...);
}

template <typename T, typename ...ARGS>
T AutoConcatenate(ARGS...args) {
  return AutoConcatenate_helper<T>(args...);
}

int main() {
  pack<string> first;
  pack<string> second;
  pack<string> third;
  pack<string> last;

  first.data = "Hello";
  first.dlen = first.data.length();

  second.data = ", ";
  second.dlen = second.data.length();

  third.data = "World";
  third.dlen = third.data.length();

  last.data = "!";
  last.dlen = last.data.length();

  cout << AutoConcatenate<string>(&first, &second, &third, &last) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

We're neither changing the declaration of `Concatenate<>()`, nor that of `AutoConcatenate<>()`, as required. We're free to implement `AutoConcatenate<>()`, as we did, and we assume that there is some implementation of `Concatenate<>()` (we provided a simple one for a working example).

Comment: You, did change the declaration of AutoConcatenation: `template<typename...ARGS> MyArray AutoConcatenation();`, there is no input as argument...  I do not think, that your solution is more elegant, because of incremental concatenation, which is too much allocating for me. I should mention, that `Concatenation(...)` method does just one allocation, no matter of argument count... My point was just to reorder input arguments or somehow expand them in above described way...

Comment: Fine, but the modifications are obvious (as far as the declaration). As far as your other concerns: well, that wasn't part of the OP. Anyway, these can be fixed with easy modifications, too. Like I said, I provided a simple implementation for a working example. You implement it any way you want, and you should take care of the allocation concerns within the implementation of Concatenate()... if you can't, then this is poor design.